# Rigol DS1074 oscilloscope shows very wrong timing

Tags: oscilloscope, timing

I have an inverted RS232 signal with 5 baud (200 ms per bit) which is sending the byte 0x33. (The first "Low" is the start bit)

When I configure my oscilloscope to 200 ms per unit it shows this signal absolutely perfect.
I use the single trigger mode (button "Single" at the right top)

[image: Rigol Oscilloscope correct timing]

As you see the timing is precise.

Now comes the weird: I caputure the same signal with the setting 500 ms per unit. It looks like this.

[image: Rigol Oscilloscope wrong timing]

To see the timing better I switch the timing to 200 ms per unit for the SAME capture and get this:

[image: Rigol Oscilloscope wrong timing]

As you see the signal seems to be slower than 200 ms per bit now.
How is that even possible on a digital oscilloscope?

In the first step the oscilloscope stores the captured data in memory.
In the second step it displays the data.
All timing is based on a precise crystal oscillator.

The only difference which I see is at the top of the screenshot where it says:

Correct capture: 10.0 MSa/s and 24.0M pts

Wrong   capture: 4.0 MSa/s and 24.0M pts

The only explanation to me seems to be a fat software bug. Are the Rigol engineers not able to do the correct conversion to display a 4.0M Samples signal? How did this oscillocope series even pass the quality control?

And yes: I have made sure that my signal is precise.
I can repeat that a hundred times:
Capturing with 200 ms per unit is perfect.
Capturing with 500 ms per unit gets wrong.

**P.D:**
Now I tested more time bases. These are the results:

```
5 seconds per unit --> OK
2 seconds per unit --> OK
1 second per unit --> OK
500 ms per unit --> wrong (constantly 4% timing error)
200 ms per unit --> OK
100 ms per unit --> OK
50 ms or less --> a period does not fit anymore
```

---

But this is just one of multiple bugs. The oscilloscope has several more bugs.

When you enable the RS232 decoder and the horizontal resolution is too small it is understandable that it does not show the hex bytes. But this is implemented so buggy that it displays completely wrong data! This screenshot shows a RS232 signal with 10400 baud and long pauses between the data packets. All the displayed "FF" are wrong.

[image: Rigol Bug Wrong RS232 Decoder data]

---

And one of the ugliest bugs is the knob "Horizontal Position". This is complete crap. It should move the signal horizontally on the screen. But it works so bad that moving the knob fast results in the signal suddenly jumping to a completely different loaction. When you move it slowly it nearly does not move at all. Such a basic functionality as navigating in a long capture with a Rigol oscilloscope is a pain!

And when you move that knob too fast you get suddenly artifacts in the signal. The same signal which I caputured above, suddenly looks like this:

[image: Rogol DS1074 bug artifacts]

Amplifying this bug you see a square signal of 2 ms period. This signal has never existed on the input of the oscilloscope. It is produced by a software bug in the oscilloscope just by moving the captured signal in memory horizontally on the screen!! Here you see a zoom of the left artifact:

[image: Rigol bug 2ms square wave signal]

And this is a zoom of the right artifact:

[image: Rigol bug artifact]

---

And as if all this would not be enough, there are more bugs. All these bugs are not reproducable. For example:

1. There is a signal but the oscilloscope does not trigger. It triggers mostly, but not always.
2. The "Single" trigger mode is enabled, but the scope does not stop after the screen is full.
3. It happened that I plug in a USB stick and the oscillscope completely freezes. All buttons were dead.

Comment: sorry, no matter how many times you think you made sure your signal is correct, I'd still put arbitrary bets that Rigol is right and your signal is wrong. Full stop – it's never the oscilloscope, it's always either the signal, misuse of the measurement device, or impedance. In your case, we can rule out the last.

Comment: Fire up your cursors and make a deltax measure of the pulse duration. What does it read?

Comment: Don't know whats for you to gain here by asking this question, if you suspect a firmware bug, e-mail Rigol.

Comment: It's interesting in that it seems to add 25 ms every 100 ms. Can you replicate it with another circuit, for instance a microcontroller doing bit banging?

Comment: @Marcus: You may think what you like, but my signal has a precision of µs. I would not have asked this question if I would have had any doubt that this is signal issue rather than an oscilloscope issue. I'am working with oscilloscopes since 30 years! And there are more ugly bugs in this scope.

Comment: @Sredni: As I expected the cursor shows the same error as the signal on the screen. For the correct signal it shows 600.0ms for the first 3 bits. For the wrong capture it shows 624.0 ms for the same period. 100% reproducable.

Comment: @S.s: I hoped someone here has the same scope and can confirm this bug. But obvioulsy I will write to Rigol. I hope they answer me.

Comment: Well fan my brow. If I set memory depth to 24M I get the same pulse dilation on my 1054z. Everything is fine and dandy with the default settings but when I put 24M my 1000ms Arduino heartbeat gets longer.

Comment: @Sredni: Waow. Did you see the update of my question? I also tested 5sec, 2sec, 1sec, and 100 ms. P.D: I already wrote the email to service@rigol.com

Comment: Wow. Please keep this question updated if you can if you discover new information, hear back from Rigol, etc.

Comment: The rigol has a test output, right? Every scope I have ever seen has one. If you can put the probe on the scope's own test output and reproduce this, that would make for a nice concise test-case for anyone who is interested. No need to use a function generator or blinkenlight or whatever.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what you say is true for the well-known big players. But Rigol? Apparently not. I wonder if it has voltage errors, too?

Comment: @mkeith verified now with the test signal: same 4% error when acquired at 500ms timescale with 24M memory depth.

Comment: @mkeith: The test output has 1kHz. When I capture it at 200ms/unit it shows: Period = 1,000ms and Frequ=1,00KHz When I capture it at 500ms/unit it shows: Period=1,044ms and Frequ=958Hz. No doubt that this is a bug. There are more bugs in this chinese oscilloscope. But it is extremely diffcult to reproduce them. This one is 100% reproducable. Just asian quality :-(  My LG TV (South Korea) has also low quality software. Although the hardware works well it seems that these companies have many flaws in firmware and quality control.

Comment: I was already convinced by your previous data. But this is a better test case for those who may have doubts and also for Rigol themselves. No other equipment is required.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think Rigol gives you good value for your money, but these are the kind of things why I spent my money on a less advanced scope from Tektronix for the same price of a Rigol, it may not have as much memory or features as the Rigol, but its a guarantee that this sort of thing wont happen. Rigol should look into this and report back.

Comment: Stupidly this page has been blocked by an admin, so I can't write my own answer. I have to leave a comment only: Today I got the definitive answer from the Rigol support.
They told me to install the firmware 04.04.04.03 from https://eu.rigol.com/products/oscillosopes/ds1000z.html
But my oscilloscope already has the latest firmware.
It displays Software Version: 00.04.04.SP4
So all these bugs that I describe are in the entire DS1000Z serie.
I doubt that Rigol will ever care to fix them as long as people are buying it and trusting Dave Jones recommendations on Youtube.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No problem, I'll get that reopened right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reopening this thread. So  I can post my answer.

My first response from Rigol support was this:

> I think this a known problem on the DS1000Z series! Please upgrade the
> firmware to version 04.04.04.03 and the capture problems should be
> solved.
>
> Follow this link to download actual firmware for your DS1074Z oscilloscope:
>
> https://eu.rigol.com/products/oscillosopes/ds1000z.html
>
> ( A short registration is required, but it's done in a minute )
> Hope I could help you on a little !

Interesting is the phrasing: "I think..." and "should be". That already gave me the impression that this is a standard answer to all their bugs: Install the
latest firmware and it "should be"  fixed.

This is on the Rigol homepage:

[image: Rigol Firmware Download]

And my scope shows:

[image: Rigol Firmware Version]

So I have 3 different versions now:

```
Support email:  04.04.04.03
Rigol Homepage: 00.04.04.04.03
Oscilloscope:   00.04.04.SP4
```

As you see: The firware versions at Rigol are not unified.

I wrote another email asking if these 3 versions are the same. The support responded that they are all the same.

Then I wrote a third email: "So I have the latest firmware. But the severe bugs are still there. When will these bugs be fixed?"

I got no answer anymore.
I wrote a fourth email to the same support guy a week later. He does not answer me anymore.

The firmware on their homepage is one year old now. The "support" does not answer anymore. So it is obvious that Rigol has zero motivation to fix their bugs.

Please note that this is the firmware for the entire DS1000Z series. So there are multiple oscilloscope models affected by these bugs.

---

The Rigol firmware is a RAR file of only 1,9 MB. I find this very strange. I expected much more.

The Upgrade Instructions say:

> - MSO/DS1000Z series digital oscilloscope does not support the downgrading operations.

This is another problem. Even if there was a new firmware available: What if the new firmware has a new bug which is even worse than the existing bugs? In this case I have no chance to go back to my previous firmware version. Rigol firmware update is a one-way road. You will never know where it leads you.

---

The Rigol homepage is a mess. If you go to "Support" -> "Software-Firmware Download" and enter Category: "Oscilloscopes" and search for "DS1074Z" you get no result at all.

If you select under product line: "DS1000Z-E" and leave "keywords" empty you will not find the same firmware as on the DS1000Z page.

https://eu.rigol.com/En/Index/listView/catid/28/tp/6/cat/7/xl/40

[image: Rigol Firmware Download]

It seems that DS1000Z and DS1000Z-E are different series. The release notes say:

```
[Model Supported] DS1202Z-E.
[Latest Revision Date] 2019-09-20
[Updated Contents]
v00.06.01.00.00 2019-09-20
     - The first version is released.
[Previous Versions and Updated Contents]
     - none
```

So this is not for my scope.

Comment: I agree with you, as long as people don't make this more public, Rigol will not correct their mistakes. To be honest, your post/question is more suitable for a forum rather than this site which is question/answer based. If I were you, I would try to make as much noise as possible about this, go to the EEVBlog and EDAboard forum and post your findings, perhaps more people like you will get things done. Good luck!

Comment: Sredni has already posted on EEVBlog. https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/rigol-1054z-and-1074z-timing-problems-at-500ms-timescale-and-24m-memory-depth/ But there are no interesting answers. Additionally I posted links under several Youtube videos about Rigol oscilloscopes. You can also help and post more comments in other places.

Comment: It's useful to know that this is an imperfect tool, so that we can keep it in mind if we chose to use it.  At the same time, it's a heck of a lot of routinely useful functionality in a cheap package.  The real tragedy here is that there isn't yet a way to combine what these companies do well in mass manufacturing economical *hardware* with a community maintained *open source software* for the SoC and FPGA.

Comment: Unfortunately the market wants to try to compete on (and even sell incremental post-purchase "features") while the engineering community would be happier with "give us a *sampler* and a software-controlled *front end* and some knobs and we'll do the rest".  A clever user who understands an imperfect tool beats an ignorant user expecting magic any day.

Comment: I don't understand: "we'll do the rest"?? The firmware is not open sorurce, how will we "do the rest"? Are you able to fix their nasty bugs? Generally I disagree with your comment. A clever user expects a correctly working device. This is what he has paid for! And Rigol is as most other chinese companies: They simply betray their clients with cheap crap. I bet fixing this bug takes about an hour for a developer who knows the code. There is NO excuse for not fixing it. I will never buy Rigol again in my entire life!

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a bug to me.
I reproduced it on my 1054z using an Arduino with an LED blinking program.

This is the signal with 12M memory depth acquired at 500ms timescale, and then expanded at 200 ms scale. The 'beat' is 1000 ms long. (Ok, technically it's 900ms long plus the overhead, but if I add the first part of the next train I get a nice 1000 ms sequence that makes numbers nicer.)

[image: 12M 500ms expanded to 200ms 1000ms]

The one above is the result I get with AUTO memory settings as well. But if I set memory depth to 24M I get problems at the 500ms scale. As above, this is the signal aquired at 500ms timescale and then expanded to 200ms timescale:

[image: 24M 500ms expanded to 200ms 1040ms]

Pulse length appears extended by 40 ms, that's the same 4ms every 100ms shown by the OP (he goes from 600ms to 624ms).
Acquisition at 200ms timescale shows the correct pulse length of 1000ms

[image: 24M 200ms 1000ms]

But if I acquire at 500ms timescale, I get 1040 ms

[image: 24M 500ms 1040ms]

Here's the Arduino Sketch, if anyone wants to replicate it.

```
/*
  doubleBlink
  Turns on and off an LED in a predetermined sequence, repeatedly.

  Most Arduinos have an on-board LED you can control. On the Uno and
  Leonardo, it is attached to digital pin 13. If you're unsure what
  pin the on-board LED is connected to on your Arduino model, check
  the documentation at http://www.arduino.cc

  This example code is in the public domain.

  modified 8 May 2014
  by Scott Fitzgerald
  modified 15 February 2016
  by Sredni Vashtar
 */


// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(100);              // wait for 0.1 second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(100);              // wait for 0.1 second
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(500);              // wait for 0.5 second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(200);              // wait for 0.2 second
}
```

(I have to say it's been a while since I last updated my scope's firmware - I'm on 00.04.04.01.01 - but the bug has been confirmed othe latest version to date)

**EDIT:** Following mkeith advice, here is the 1kHz scope test signal, acquired at 500ms timescale and then expanded at 200us, when memory depth is set to 24M.

[image: 24M 1kHz signal 500ms expanded to 200us]

The period becomes 1.040 ms. Same 4% error. Acquisition at 200us directly will give the correct value of 1.000 ms.

And it gets better! If I acquire the test signal with a timebase of 5s, and then expand it to 200us, the period becomes 800 us!
That's a 20% error.

[image: 24M 1kHz signal 5s expanded to 200us]

At other timebases (with the same stopped acquisition) I get the correct value. I would love to see how they do the rounding in Rigol.

Anyhwow, this bug is affecting the latest firmware version - as noted by the OP - and since the question has been closed, people interested might want to follow [this thread on the EEVBlog forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/rigol-1054z-and-1074z-timing-problems-at-500ms-timescale-and-24m-memory-depth/).

Comment: Rigol is really chinese CRAP. Have a look at my posting. I added some more screenshots. Did you also see this?

Comment: @Elmue I was aware of the sluggishness in the trace positioning but I had no occasion to see the artifacts in serial decode. I consider these minor problems for an entry level scope in this price range. They are inconveniences but I consider them a tradeoff for the low price. The timing bug, on the contrary is a serious bug and there is no "but the price is low" excuse for that. That bug **needs** fixing. For the rest, I consider my 1054z a nice toy to have at home. A toy I would not trust with my life, or the life of my mosquitos...

Comment: Also, it is a known shortcoming of the 1000z series that all measurements are made on the displayed data and not on the data stored in memory. I consider those measurements a help to a 'manual' reading by counting the spacing on the graticule, nothing more. And yes, I concur that the decoding function is little more than a gimmick as it relies on the data being clearly displayed on the screen.

Comment: I think there are no excuses for these bugs. People argue that these Rigol scopes are cheaper than other brands. But the price depends mainly on the hardware cost and the hardware is OK. The software is buggy. They have so many oscilloscope models that I got confused when I bought mine. Instead of producing more and more models they should fix their old bugs and all would be perfect. They could sell high quality for the SAME price if they wanted. Also there are so many features that you will hardly ever use. I would prefer less features if the basic functionality would be bug-free.

Comment: @Elmue like I said earlier, I rather invest in a Tektronix scope even if its more rudimental and outdated than a Rigol scope for the same price. Rigol scopes have many channels, many features, more memory, and so on, but Tek scopes are much more reliable. Thats why I don't care when Dave Jones makes fun of Tek scopes in favour of Rigol scopes. You should send Rigol the link of this question just so they know, they are the dominant brand of the hobby/low cost market, they should at least be aware of the crap they make, I wonder if the same thing happens with GW Instek and Siglent.

Comment: Stupidly this page has been blocked by an admin, so I can't write my own answer. I have to leave a comment only: Today I got the definitive answer from the Rigol support.
They told me to install the firmware 04.04.04.03 from https://eu.rigol.com/products/oscillosopes/ds1000z.html
But my oscilloscope already has the latest firmware.
It displays Software Version: 00.04.04.SP4
So all these bugs that I describe are in the entire DS1000Z serie.
I doubt that Rigol will ever care to fix them as long as people are buying it and trusting Dave Jones recommendations on Youtube.

Comment: Which firmware version is in your scope?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott  Answer updated. It's 00 04 04 01 01

Answer (score 4):

Own DS1054Z too, the latest software (00.04.04.04.03) is installed, this bug shows up too.  Had a call with Rigol, they say that this references their bug #297 opened in August 2020 and they had reproduced it internally, but there is no concrete plans for the next firmware release in their system.  The support engineer was unable to give any timeline for this (and mentioned the "old hardware that is hard to predict new software version releases"), so, I think, more Rigol DS1xxxZ owners should poll Rigol support and ask them to fix the issue: may be such a pressure will make them to produce a new software version.

The engineer in question was Chris Armstrong (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3ZbcRb6AeM, chris_armstrong@rigol.com), so people can keep him CC'ed in their bug reports: he seems to be a sane and nice person.

Hope that will help us all.

Comment: Or maybe he told you just an excuse? Maybe they don't have any plans at all to fix their ugly bugs? This is my impression.

Comment: I am going to poll the status in a week, so we'll see.  But at least the mentioned date of the bug being opened correlates with report/discussion dates at EEVblog, https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/rigol-1054z-and-1074z-timing-problems-at-500ms-timescale-and-24m-memory-depth/

Comment: I wish I were so optimistic as you. Note that since one year they did not release a new firmware version for the entire DS1000Z series although there are multiple ugly bugs.

Comment: Got answers from various Rigol divisions: European folks are going to reproduce it next week in their lab.  Chinese folks said that they are analyzing the signal from the screen data (and not from the raw acquired points) and it is the design limitation of DS1000Z.  I am not convinced that nothing can be done, so trying to understand what/why really happens in the 1000Z series.

Comment: All timings are working except 500ms. They have a function in their code which translates the capture data into screen data. This function has a bug for 500ms per display unit. What is there which you don't understand? This is a bug which is VERY easy to fix, because all timings are working correctly except one. If I had the source code I would fix that in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution, but I can confirm this affect other models.

I just measured the 1kHz scope probe test signal on my MSO1104Z, and when I have it sampling at 4MSa/s I also see a period readout of 1.040ms.  If I sample at 2MSa/s or 10MSa/s it reads correctly at 1.000ms.

[image: 1kHz at 4MSa/s 500ms per div zoomed]

My MSO1104Z system info page also shows it is running version 00.04.04.SP4, but according to my records the last firmware I loaded was 00.04.04.04.02.  So I downloaded and installed 00.04.04.04.03 from the Rigol website.  Now the system info page helpfully still shows 00.04.04.SP4, and as expected the timing problem still exists with 4MSa/s acquisition.

[image: Same info shown for both firmware releases]

I've return the acquisition memory depth setting to auto on my scope to hopefully avoid seeing this again when I use the scope and forget that I changed it to 24Mpts.

Edit to add: I attempted to reproduce with the logic analyser inputs, but I couldn't get a 4MSa/s data rate with those enabled.  I couldn't reproduce with any of the other acquisition settings I tried either.

Comment: Do you get 800us for the test signal when acquired at 24M with 5 seconds timebase?

Comment: I get total garbage for the period measurement at 5s/div.
Depending on zoom I get various readings like 10us, 20us, 400us, 800us, and 1ms.